# Command: `cmake . .`

Tags: cmake

I use `cmake` (https://cmake.org) to compile a program. However, I don't understand this command:

`cmake . .`

Comment: What don’t you understand about it? Where are you being told to run this command? Are you sure it isn’t `cmake ..`, with no space between the two `.`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [command line reference](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/manual/cmake.1.html) shows that the positional arguments to `cmake` are either `<path-to-source>` or `<path-to-existing-build>`. However, the use of two positional arguments (as in your case) is not documented. It causes the first position argument to be the `<path-to-source>` (assuming it contains a `CMakeList.txt`), and the second to be the project binary directory.

Using two current directory (`.`) position arguments is equivalent to using only one, as the project binary directory defaults to the current directory if none is provided on the command line. Usually when using CMake and creating an out-of-source build, CMake would be run from the project binary directory, and the path to the source directory (only) is provided. This is the [recommended](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#Out-of-source_build_trees) use case.